# Generating random sprites

Tags: random, sprite

I am just a beginner and was doing some time with games and got a problem

```
package minigames;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class fallingball extends JPanel {


   int x = 250;
   int y = 0;

   private void moveBall() {
      y = y + 1;


   }


   public void paint(Graphics g){
      super.paint(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2d.setColor(Color.black);
      g2d.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Falling Ball");
      fallingball game = new fallingball();
      f.add(game);
      f.setSize(500, 500);
      f.setResizable(false);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      while (true) {
         game.moveBall();
         game.repaint();
         Thread.sleep(10);
      }
   }

}
```

only 1 ball is generated and it gets fallen down. i wanted to generate balls falling randomly and from different x co-ordinate in the frame how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for the random x you want to

```
import java.util.Random();
```

and use

```
Random rnd = new Random();
x = rnd.nextInt(<HIGHEST X VALUE POSSIBLE>)+1;
```

That will make a random integer from 0 to the max X value and assign it to x. NOTE (it's +1 because rnd.nextInt(n) creates a value from 0 to n-1.
To get more balls to keep falling try this in your loop:

```
while (true) {
     game.moveBall();
     game.repaint();
     Thread.sleep(10);
     if (y >= <MAX y>) {
      y = 0;
      x = rnd.nextInt(<max x>)+1;
    }
  }
```

You just need to reset the y when it goes off screen, otherwise it's just falling lower and lower without being visible. This is a fast solution. Ideally you would use objects and create/destroy them when off screen, this will make only 1 keep falling randomly. Adjust it as needed.
**Also please read here for a game loop:**
http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0

```
while (true)
```

is a pretty bad gameloop

Comment: tx jrafferty for the help and as you said i will go further with the link and try those and if any problems i will sure comment

Comment: sure, didn't mean to sound rude; and it's fine to use what you had for testing, etc. but when you get really into it, there's way better ways to update game assets that will run better on all machines. I'm still working on this stuff myself. Good luck